# toggle checkbox logically to show/hide div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could someone tell me how to show and hide div loggically

```
$scope.showChildDiv = false;
var resp = {
    prop1: {
        'data1':'asd'
    }
}
$scope.showDiv = function(){
    !$scope.showChildDiv = $scope.showChildDiv;
    if(resp.prop1) {

    }
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' ng-click='showDiv()' ng-model='clickMe'/>

<div class='showThisDiv' ng-If='showChildDiv'></div>
```

How to achieve below scenarios,

need to show div, if  `showChildDiv` is `false` and `resp` has `prop1`

need to show div, if checkbox is checked and `showChildDiv` is `false`

Comment: Why not `ng-if="clickMe"`?

Comment: @AlonEitan thats not working bro, i've updated, trying to say clearly as much as i can . apologize if still am not clear

Comment: I created a simple snippet showing how it should be done using the `clickMe` model directly, and also with your approach https://jsfiddle.net/3d82b9yz/

Comment: The main issue is this: `!$scope.showChildDiv = $scope.showChildDiv;` - It throw the following error: `SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` - It should be `$scope.showChildDiv = !$scope.showChildDiv;`

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, you're right, but by default i want show div when it was not checked thats why im trying to have the if condition inside that function, thats where i've got jammed

Comment: almost i got, but buy default not showing `$scope.showDiv = function() {
    $scope.showChildDiv = !$scope.showChildDiv;
    if (!$scope.showChildDiv && resp.prop1) {
      $scope.showChildDiv = true;
    }
  }`

Comment: Maybe something like this then? https://jsfiddle.net/L7n9dger/

Comment: @AlonEitan Im sorry, may the way i explain is totally wrong. ok let me try by myself and comeback. Thanks for your effort